# Printf before fork() is being printed twice

Tags: c, printf, multiprocessing, fork

I was writing a multi-process program using `fork()` and i bumped into a problem.

Below is a sample code reproducing the problem (without any sort of error checking):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world");
  fork();
}
```

This code prints 2 "hello world" statements (one from parent and the other from child). However this should not be the case since the `printf`function call is prior to the `fork()` system call. 
After testing, the problem appears to be solved by the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello world\n"); \\ addition of the new line character 
  // or by using fflush(stdout); 
  fork();
}
```

My guessing is that the `printf` buffer is being copied while its not flushed, so the child process is emptying its copy of this buffer before exiting. Hence the other `printf` shows.

Can anyone provide a better explanation of this issue? Or even better, correct me if i am wrong or missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file handle `stdout` (which is used by `printf`) is by default *line buffered*, which means output using `printf` will be flushed (and shown in the console) either when there's a newline or when the buffer is full.

As `fork` creates an exact duplicate of the parent process, both processes have the same contents in the (un-flushed) output buffer, and both will be flushed when the two processes exits.

So yes you're correct in your guessing.

Comment: Great. So even though the forking is happening after the `printf`, the `stdout` buffer is still being copied since the child process is a duplicate or a clone that shares most of the parents data (including stack, heap, text etc.. ). Thanks for your clarification.